# Configure Jetty cluster to share web Sessions

Tags: java, jetty

I'm new with Jetty. I'm trying to setup a cluster including 2 [Jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/) servers with [HAProxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/) as the load balancer. However, the two Jetty servers worked separately without sharing sessions.

I found this [document](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Jetty+Clustering+with+WADI) that instructs to use WABI. But it seems the document is deprecated because it used Jetty 6.

I'm using jetty-distribution-8.1.8. How can I configure this?

Thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- database - http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Session_Clustering_Using_a_Database
- mongodb - http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/MongoDB_Session_Clustering

There are some other nosql based ones floating around as well, there is a memcached one on github.  My general recommendation would be to go for the database approach initially and once you have the experience with that and understand the nuances look to others if that one doesn't fit the bill.